# R : How to obtain the fitting values from distribution fit?

Tags: r

I fit gamma distribution on empirical distribution function using the $fitdist$ function:

```
fit = fitdist(data=empdistr,distr="gamma")
```

I then use the $denscomp$ function to compare data to fitted values:

```
dc = denscomp(fit)
```

But I would like to extract from $fit$ or from $dc$ the actual fitted values, i.e. the points of the gamma density (with the fitted parameters) which are displayed in the $denscomp$ function.

Does anybody have an idea of how I can do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dgamma` to predict the density for a given quantile:

```
dgamma(x, coef(fit)[1], coef(fit)[2])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
However, I would like to find a way to straightforwardly obtain the good "x" in the dgamma function.

Comment: You seem to be confused. What is a 'good "x"'? `denscomp` just plots `dgamma` for quantiles between 0 and 35.

Comment: My question about the right "x" to put is the following: if I want to mimic the plot produced by dencomp, I should write hist(empdistr) and plot(dgamma(x, coef(fit)[1], coef(fit)[2])), but what value should I give to variable x ? I tried x = 0:35 but it doesn't work (it is a kind of shifted).

Comment: `denscomp` derives the range of x values from the data. Look at its code to learn how. (0 to 35 was from my simulated data, which I didn't include in my answer. You should have included a reproducible example in your question.) Also, you should not use `plot`, but `curve` instead.